# Html.Display extension not outputting value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use the following code to print user name.

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   @Html.Display("Welcome, " + User.Identity.Name);
}
```

But it doesn't  print it.

Why?

Comment: Uh `IsAuthenticated == false` I'd imagine

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to see what is the value at run time ?

Comment: @Lostdreamer Yes I did it. It has a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Html.Display` is not meant to display strings, but properties from your model. Try something like this:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   @: Welcome, @User.Identity.Name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution:

```
 @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
           {
               <label>Welcome, </label>  @Html.Label(User.Identity.Name);
           }
```